# while if statements, am not sure how to use a while statement when a name is not equal to quit

Tags: python

I am learning how to do while if statements and am unsure how to do step 2 in this program, "use a while statement to test when the name is not equal to quit". I tried to assign a variable to "name" but am not sure if that is the right way to go about it.

```
# Write the statements requested in Steps 1-6 below
# See the examples in the provided code
# Use structured programming and indent your code.
# Programmer Name: *****add your name here****

import random

# uses randrange instead of randint for better results in Python 3.7 
# randrange stops just before the upper range, use (1, 11) for 1-10

num = random.randrange(1, 11)

# Step 1: Ask the player to enter a name or quit to exit

 print("Hi, please enter your name or type 'quit' to exit.")    
   
# Step 2: use a while statement to test when the name is not equal to quit

        a=name
   while a

  # Step 3: input enter a number from 1 to 10 for the variable your_guess
   

   
    # display the number guessed
    print("Your number is", your_guess)

    while num != your_guess:

        # Step 4: Write an if statement for your_guess is less than num
    

            print("Your guess is too low.")
            your_guess = int(input("Guess another number from 1 to 10: "))

        elif your_guess > num:
            print("Your guess is too high")
            your_guess = int(input("Guess another number from 1 to 10: "))

        else:
            break

    print("The correct number was", num)
    # Step 5 display text with your guess and You won, name



    print("***************************************************************")
    # Step 6 ask the player to enter a name or quit to exit


    num = random.randrange(1, 11)
print("Thank you for playing!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The program is bascially asking you to check whether the user has typed in `quit` instead of a number.

I don't see you take in the input entered by the user in the program, maybe you should try and do

```
print("Hi, please enter your name or type 'quit' to exit.")
your_guess = input()
```

Then you have to check whether `your_guess` is equal to `'quit'` because that should terminate the loop (stop it from running and exit the program).

```
while your_guess != 'quit':
```

P.S. Make sure to say `your_guess = int(your_guess)` to convert it to a string inside the loop, or else it will be evaluated as a string.